# How can I extract the bigger value for each key in a list of hashes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, collections, hash, functional-programming, max

I can imagine there is a simple way to do that instead of use many variables and state.

I just want to get the highest value given for each key in a list of hashes

For example:

```
[{1=>19.4}, {1=>12.4}, {2=>29.4}, {3=>12.4}, {2=>39.4}, {2=>59.4}]
```

Result

```
[{1=>19.4}, {3=>12.4}, {2=>59.4}]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd do as below :

```
a = [{1=>19.4}, {1=>12.4}, {2=>29.4}, {3=>12.4}, {2=>39.4}, {2=>59.4}]

# the below is the main trick, to group the hashes and sorted the key/value pair
# in **ascending order**.
a.sort_by(&:to_a)
# => [{1=>12.4}, {1=>19.4}, {2=>29.4}, {2=>39.4}, {2=>59.4}, {3=>12.4}]

# then using the trick in mind, we know hash can't have duplicate keys, so
# blindly I can rely on `Enumerable#inject` with the `Hash#merge` method.
a.sort_by(&:to_a).inject(:merge)
# => {1=>19.4, 2=>59.4, 3=>12.4}

# final one
a.sort_by(&:to_a).inject(:merge).map { |k,v| {k => v} }
# => [{1=>19.4}, {2=>59.4}, {3=>12.4}]
```

Comment: @coffee Its for yours.. :)

Answer (score 3):

This is a variant of @Matt's answer:

```
 a.group_by(&:keys).map {|k,v| {k.first => v.map(&:values).flatten.max}}
   #=> [{1=>19.4}, {2=>59.4}, {3=>12.4}]
```

Answer (score 3):

How about this?

```
Hash[a.flat_map(&:to_a).sort_by(&:last)]
# a.flat_map(&:to_a).sort_by(&:last).to_h for Ruby 2.1+ as @steenslag suggested
=> {3=>12.4, 1=>19.4, 2=>59.4}
```

Here's the `fruity` benchmark comparison:

```
require 'fruity'
a = 1000.times.collect { |i| { rand(100) => rand(1000) } }

compare do
  caryswoveland { 
   a.group_by(&:keys).map {|k,v| {k.first => v.map(&:values).flatten.max}} 
  }
  matt { a.group_by(&:keys).map { |k,v| v.max_by { |j| j[k[0]] } } }
  steenslag { 
    a.each_with_object({}){|h, res| 
      res.merge!(h){|k, *vals| res[k] = vals.max} 
    } 
  }
  abdo { Hash[a.flat_map(&:to_a).sort_by(&:last)] }
end
```

Output:

```
Running each test 4 times. Test will take about 1 second.
abdo is similar to steenslag (results differ..)
steenslag is faster than matt by 30.000000000000004% ± 10.0%
matt is faster than caryswoveland by 30.000000000000004% ± 10.0%
```

Comment: Nice and compact, Abdo, but a couple of problems: your output is a hash, whereas an array of hashes is required and `sort` is more time-consuming than `max`.  You should be able to fix the first problem easily.  I initially made the same mistake, and believe a hash may be better here.

Comment: Agreed that it's not the required result.. I think I like my hash better though haha :-) You're right about sort but it looks like according to the benchmark, it's being faster.. weird

Comment: `p a.flat_map(&:to_a).sort_by(&:last).to_h` (Ruby 1.2.1) is really starting to look good

Comment: Interesting test results.  Could you please change 100 and 1000 to something larger and report the effect that has?  I'd be interested in knowing if `sort` will maintain its dominance.

Comment: I did `a = 10000.times.collect { |i| { rand(1000) => rand(10000) } }`, steenslag is 10% +- 10% faster than abdo, abdo is 20% +- 10% faster than matt and caryswoveland. I then did `a = 10000.times.collect { |i| { rand(10000) => rand(10000) } }` (more dispersed keys), steenslag is ~70% faster than abdo, abdo ~50% faster than matt and matt is ~80% faster than caryswoveland.

Comment: @steenslag is that ruby 2.1.1 ? (I wanna make sure so I can update my post =) )

Comment: Thanks, Abdo.  Please keep testing until you can report a result that does not have me dead last.  :-)

Comment: Cary, I think this can be architecture dependent... sort's performance on my macbook is puzzling me =)

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [{1=>19.4}, {1=>12.4}, {2=>29.4}, {3=>12.4}, {2=>39.4}, {2=>59.4}]

a.group_by(&:keys).map { |k,v| v.max_by { |j| j[k[0]] } }
```

> [{1=>19.4}, {2=>59.4}, {3=>12.4}]

Credit to Cary Swoveland for `group_by(&:keys)`.

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [{1=>19.4}, {1=>12.4}, {2=>29.4}, {3=>12.4}, {2=>39.4}, {2=>59.4}]

p a.each_with_object({}){|h, res| res.merge!(h){|k, *vals| res[k] = vals.max} }
#=> {1=>19.4, 2=>59.4, 3=>12.4}
```

Comment: steen, consider `each_with_object({})`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Yeah I know it's better style. Hate the name though. Why not `each_with` ?